# Django Multiple Forms from differents models

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

i m quite new with Django but i m stuck since a day on a problem that i can t solve.

I have to create forms with  a lot of fields. The fields comes from different models and i want to save them all at once. I want to display it with a slick so the user experience will be better and not overwhelmed by the amout of fields to fill. The slick part is not a problem. My problem is to render multiple form separated in different div on the same page. In this i want to display the candidateDetails form not only the candidate one.

here my actual code for only one form that is working.

The forms :

```
class CandidateApplicationForm(ModelForm):
position = forms.ChoiceField(choices=POSITION, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

class Meta:
    model = Candidate
    fields = ['firstName',
              'lastName',
              'mailAddress',
              'address',
              'city',
              'country',
              'nationality',
              'position',
              ]
    widgets = {
        'firstName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        'lastName': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        'nationality': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
        'Type of programme': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input'}),
    }
```

class CandidateDetailsForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = CandidatesDetail
    fields = ['birthPlace',
              'birthDate',
              'nationality',
             ]
```

The Views :

class RegisterCandidate:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.method = None

def candidateapply(request):

    apply = candidateregistrationform.CandidateApplicationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_candidate = candidateregistrationform.CandidateApplicationForm(request.POST)
        if form_candidate.is_valid():

            candidate = form_candidate.save(commit=False)
            candidate.save()

        else:
            apply = candidateregistrationform.CandidateApplicationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'candidateapplication.html',
                  {'form': apply})


def candidatedetails(request):
    apply = candidateregistrationform.CandidateDetailsForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_candidatedetails = candidateregistrationform.CandidateDetailsForm(request.POST)
        if form_candidatedetails.is_valid():

            candidate = form_candidatedetails.save(commit=False)
            candidate.save()

        else:
            apply = candidateregistrationform.CandidateApplicationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'candidateapplication.html',
                  {'form': apply})
```

And the HTML :

```
{% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
  <p>
    {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
    {{ field }}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what the `RegisterCandidate` class is supposed to do. Just instantiate your two forms in one view like you would do with one form. Give them a different name (candidate_form and details_form) and display them both in your template. In your view, create them both, check if both are valid and if both are valid, save them both.

Comment: Also add a prefix to each form so that the field names are prefixed and different for each form, I see both forms have the 'nationality' field for example.

Comment: I wrapped it in a class mainly because as i come from .Net we put everything in a class. So i tryed what you said and i cant make it work. I can access both of the form but on differents pages. When i try to call both on the same page, only the def registred in the urls.py is displayed.

Comment: As I said, you need to make one view, it sounds like you're still making two. One request = one view.

Comment: Ok thanks ! its working. Actually i did something very similar to what you explained but i messed up with my return. Now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, as dirkgroten said, create a single view function with two forms in it:

```
def candidatedetails(request):
    candidate_application_form = candidateregistrationform.CandidateApplicationForm()
    candidate_details_form = candidateregistrationform.CandidateDetailsForm()

    ...

    return render(request,
                  'candidateapplication.html',
                  {'candidate_application_form': candidate_application_form, 
                    'candidate_details_form', candidate_details_form})
```

now you'll be able to render these forms or specific fields

`{{ candidate_application_form }}`

Comment: Great ! Thanks to both of you. Actually i came accross by myself to a similar solution earlyer but i did a mistake i was doing an error with my return like :
{'candidate_application_form': candidate_application_form}, 
                    {'candidate_details_form', candidate_details_form})

Instead of what you did. Its working perfectly now !